# Whats the native, default index class of a xts object?

Tags: r, xts

I am converting an object to xts, don't know which index class should I choose.
I try to find out which index class the system will pick by default, I type

```
class(index(as.xts(sample_matrix)))
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Which one is the default(native) index class of a xts object? How can an object belong to two type of class the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An object can belong to several classes.  Note that xts objects inherit from zoo, so xts objects themselves have several classes.

```
> class(as.xts(sample_matrix))
[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

`POSIXct` is the default class for the index of xts objects.  `POSIXt` is a virtual class from which both `POSIXct` and `POSIXlt` inherit, which allows you to mix operations between the two classes.

```
> s <- Sys.time()
> class(s)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
> s - as.POSIXlt(s)
Time difference of 0 secs
```

If `POSIXct` and `POSIXlt` did not both inherit from `POSIXt`, then this would happen:

```
> s - as.Date(s)
[1] "2014-02-26 03:01:54 CST"
Warning message:
Incompatible methods ("-.POSIXt", "-.Date") for "-"
```

More details can be found in `?POSIXt`.

Comment: Are you the author of TTR package?

Comment: Well, thanks for answering my question, and nice to meet you.